# Fusion Builder Repeater

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a Custom Slider, the problem is that I am not sure how to add a repeater to fusion builder.

```
    function fusion_element_custom_slider() {     
       fusion_builder_map( 
        array(
            'name'            => esc_attr__( 'Custom Slider', 'fusion-builder' ),
            'shortcode'       => 'fusion_custom_slider',
            'icon'          => 'fusiona-uniF61C',
            'allow_generator' => true,
            'params'          => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'repeater',
                    'heading' => __( 'Slides', 'fusion-builder' ),
                    'param_name' => 'slides',
                    'params'    => array(
                        array(
                            'type'        => 'textfield',
                            'heading'     => esc_attr__( 'Title', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'description' => esc_attr__( 'Enter overlay text of image.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'param_name'  => 'element_image_overlay_text',
                            'value'       => esc_attr__( '', 'fusion-builder' ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'type'        => 'upload_images',
                            'heading'     => esc_attr__( 'Background Image', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'description' => esc_attr__( 'Upload or select images.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                            'param_name'  => 'element_background_image',
                            'value'       => '',
                        ),
                    )
                )

            ),
        )   ); 

} 
add_action( 'fusion_builder_before_init','fusion_element_custom_slider' );
```

Not sure if this is how it works.
When I add `type => 'repeater'` all I see in WordPress backend is some empty repeater rows and not some rows containing the textfield the image.

I could not find an example in the documentation https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/fusion-builder/configure/add-preview-template-for-my-fusion-builder-element/

Answer (score 0):

```
function fusion_element_parent() {
    fusion_builder_map( array(
        'name'          => esc_attr__( 'Checklist', 'fusion-builder' ),
        'shortcode'     => 'fusion_checklist',
        'multi'         => 'multi_element_parent',
        'element_child' => 'fusion_li_item',
        'params'        => array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'tinymce',
                'heading'     => esc_attr__( 'Content', 'fusion-builder' ),
                'description' => esc_attr__( 'Enter some content for this contentbox.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                'param_name'  => 'element_content',
                'value'       => 'Default value',
            ),
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'fusion_builder_before_init', 'fusion_element_parent' );


function fusion_element_child() {
    fusion_builder_map( array(
        'name'              => esc_attr__( 'List Item', 'fusion-builder' ),
        'description'       => esc_attr__( 'Enter some content for this textblock', 'fusion-builder' ),
        'shortcode'         => 'fusion_li_item',
        'hide_from_builder' => true,
        'params'            => array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'tinymce',
                'heading'     => esc_attr__( 'List Item Content', 'fusion-builder' ),
                'description' => esc_attr__( 'Add list item content.', 'fusion-builder' ),
                'param_name'  => 'element_content',
                'value'       => 'Default value',
                'placeholder' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'fusion_builder_before_init', 'fusion_element_child' );
```

Documentation:
https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/fusion-builder/configure/add-new-multi-element-nested-shortcode-fusion-builder/

The idea is to have a parent with more children this will act like a repeater.